# How can I get a MAPI Folder that isn't a subfolder of Inbox?

Tags: outlook

There are many questions that ask how to get a folder in Outlook, but all the answers I've seen assume that this folder is nested underneath the inbox folder. Even [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268863.aspx) assumes this:

```
private void SetCurrentFolder()
{
    string folderName = "TestFolder";

    //THIS STATEMENT ASSUMES WE'RE LOOKING IN THE INBOX
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    try
    {
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = inBox.
            Folders[folderName];
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.Display();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no folder named " + folderName +
            ".", "Find Folder Name");
    }
}
```

Let's say that I have the following folders at the root level of my mailbox:

- `Inbox`
- `Drafts`
- `MyCustomFolder`

**How do I get `MyCustomFolder`, which is not a subfolder of the inbox, as a `MAPIFolder` or `Folder`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the folder is a peer of the Inbox folder, you can get the Inbox, then go up one level, then retrieve the folder in question:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Outlook.MAPIFolder rootFolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)inBox.Parent;
Outlook.MAPIFolder myFolder = rootFolder.Folders["MyCustomFolder"];
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will work. It still seems strange to me that there's not a more straightforward way to do this provided by Microsoft.

Comment: More straightforward way would be to use Namespace.Folders collection that represents top level folders of all stores in the profile. You can then drill down to the folder you are after.